# Regular expressions dual aspect component

Tags: regex

Sorry for the confusing title, I could not think of the correct wording. I am trying to understand if there is a way for regex to match different strings, depending on whether a previous capture group was captured or not.

```
/th?u(e|r)sday/
```

This matches `tuesday`, `thursday` but also `thuesday` and `tursday`. Is there any way to indicate in the regex that a part should only match, if a previous part was matched... so I imagine a potential syntax like... `(?#:pattern)` where `#` is a number from a capturing group, and if the capturing group captured, then pattern is included, otherwise it is skipped. A similar pattern `(!#:pattern)` for if the `#`th group is not captured. This invented syntax is to demonstrate what I am trying to do. With this invented syntax, I could solve my problem above like this...

```
/t(h)?u(!1:e)(?1:r)sday/
```

Is there any such syntax in regex to achieve this type of referencing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature does exist in some regex implementations, and the regex from your example would be written like this:

```
/t(h)?u(?(1)r|e)sday/
```

Obviously this is not the best example, since `/t(hur|ue)sday/` is equivalent and much shorter, but there are cases where this is more useful.

Check out the second to last element in the table of [this advanced regex reference page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html), with additional information on conditionals [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html).

- Syntax:

  ```
  (?(1)then|else)
  ```
- Description:

  > If the first capturing group took part in the match attempt thus far, the "then" part must match for the overall regex to match. If the first capturing group did not take part in the match, the "else" part must match for the overall regex to match.
- Example:

  `(a)?(?(1)b|c)` matches `ab`, the first `c` and the second `c` in `babxcac`

According to the same page, conditionals are supported by the [JGsoft engine](http://www.regular-expressions.info/jgsoft.html), [Perl](http://www.regular-expressions.info/perl.html), [PCRE](http://www.regular-expressions.info/pcre.html) and the [.NET framework](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a more specific disjunction?

```
/t(hur|ue)sday/
```

Comment: Because it is a contrived example, for a more general principal of what could be a useful feature. I want to use it as a feature in much more complex matches. This does not really help to answer my question... I mean I could just do `/tuesday|thursday/` right?

Comment: Here is an example of my idea being used more usefully: `^((From|To)|Subject): ((?(2)\w+@\w+\.[a-z]+|.+))` (from: http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html)